# elastic beanstalk 777 permissions on folder

Tags: amazon-web-services, permissions, amazon-elastic-beanstalk

Cant get 777 permissions to work on deploy on elastic beanstalk I have this in my .ebextensions folder on a .config file but I always get an error deployig:

```
container_commands:
  01storage_permissions:
    command: "chmod -fR 777 /var/app/current/uploads/"
  02storage_permissions:
    command: "chmod -fR 777 /var/app/current/app/storage/"
```

I also tried

```
container_commands:
  01storage_permissions:
    command: "chmod -fR 777 /var/app/ondeck/uploads/"
  02storage_permissions:
    command: "chmod -fR 777 /var/app/ondeck/app/storage/"
```

Error:

```
[Instance: i-ee305727 Module: AWSEBAutoScalingGroup ConfigSet: null] Command failed on instance. Return code: 1 Output: [CMD-AppDeploy/AppDeployStage0/EbExtensionPostBuild] command failed with error code 1: Error occurred during build: Command 01storage_permissions failed.
```

Any Ideas? Thanks!

Comment: It should work. If you're not sure what the path is, you can try to ssh into your instance and see by yourself: `ssh -t ec2-user@ec2-xxx-xxx-xxx-xxx.location.compute.amazonaws.com`.

Comment: are you sure this path exist before the application starts?

Answer (score 0):

If the path exists, you could also try:

```
 01storage_permissions:
    command: "chmod -fR 777 /var/app/current/uploads/"
    owner: root
    group: root
```